# The reputation icon show plus sign while my reputation score decrease

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

I saw +20 (with bold and green color) at the top bar reputation icon. I thought I earned 20 points when I opened the dropdown it shows this:

[image]

This is really confusing. I know its hard to handle the cases and to show when we have mix reputation changes e.g. upvotes + downvotes to decide if there will be a red color and minus sign or a green color with plus sign. So maybe we should improve the tooltip to handle it properly, instead of always showing a plus sign even when you have lost reputation score?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The counter on the top shows the *change in reputation* since you last clicked it.

You haven't clicked on the icon since [the UTC morning of December 18th](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860103/aamir-adnan?tab=reputation) at least. Since that time you gained +40 in votes and accepts, and you lost -20 when a user account was removed. That means that your *net gain* since that time was +20.