# Why my reputation popup in "Recent Achievements" shows incorrect value?

Tags: support, reputation

I observed this popup in Recent Achievements.

[image: Popup]

Note the increased reputation is +4 in popup and pane below shows +10.

Other parts of Stack Overflow increased reputation +10 correctly.

[image: Tab]

[image: Main]

Only the popup shows incorrect value.

This has happened multiple times earlier. As value at all other locations is correct, I do not take any further step.

But this time, I decided to ask here to understand the reason.

Following is some part of the data from log printed using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) link:

```
-- 2018-03-06 rep -4    = 3151      
 2  40827671 (10)
-- 2018-03-07 rep +10   = 3161      
-- 2018-03-09 rep 0     = 3161      
-- 2018-03-10 rep 0     = 3161      
-- 2018-03-11 rep 0     = 3161      
 2  46690734 (10)
-- 2018-03-13 rep +10   = 3171
```

Comment: Probably there is a -6 on other SE sites.

Comment: The reputation dropdown won't show you negative events.  Those get swallowed up until your next positive event.  So that +10 turning into a +4 suggests events like (-2, -2, -2, +10).

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280948/the-reputation-icon-show-plus-sign-while-my-reputation-score-decrease

Comment: Yes, that too. @ryanyuyu What was the design decision that doesn't inform users of negative reputation change?

Comment: @user202729: I am only active (mostly) on SO. There is no reputation change on other SE site. Anyway, if it was so, it should be listed in pane below.

Comment: I'm not sure.  If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation while logged in, you can see a full audit of your own reputation.  Perhaps some other hidden event, like an unupvote or something weird.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: If I remember correctly, my reputation before this change was 3161. Answer upvote added +10 which makes it 3171 which is correct. If there was any other downvote or negative change between this, it should also reflect in total reputation which is not the case. By the way; link is really good; thanks.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Edited the question to add some part of log from the link you suggested.